# Network returning nonetype parameters

Tags: neural-network, mlp

This code is supposed to construct a network composed of two sections. first section is an mlp with a single output(u) and the second part consists of a vector [du/dx, -du/dt] and I'm training this vector output based on the input X = [x,t]. But when I run the code it returns nonetype parameters. What do you guys think is wrong?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy as np
from choose_optimizer import *
from functorch import make_functional
from functorch import vmap
from functorch import jacrev

`# CUDA support
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device('cuda')
else:
    device = torch.device('cpu')

def div(u):
    """Accepts a function u:R^D -> R^D."""
    J = torch.func.jacrev(u)
    return lambda x: torch.trace(J(x))

# the deep neural network
class DNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, layers, activation, use_batch_norm=False, use_instance_norm=False):
        super(DNN, self).__init__()

        # parameters
        self.depth = len(layers) - 1

        if activation == 'identity':
            self.activation = torch.nn.Identity
        elif activation == 'tanh':
            self.activation = torch.nn.Tanh
        elif activation == 'relu':
            self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU
        elif activation == 'gelu':
            self.activation = torch.nn.GELU
        elif activation == 'sin':
            self.activation = sin
        self.use_batch_norm = use_batch_norm
        self.use_instance_norm = use_instance_norm

        layer_list = list()
        for i in range(self.depth - 1):
            layer_list.append(
                ('layer_%d' % i, torch.nn.Linear(layers[i], layers[i+1]))
            )

            if self.use_batch_norm:
                layer_list.append(('batchnorm_%d' % i, torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=layers[i+1])))
            if self.use_instance_norm:
                layer_list.append(('instancenorm_%d' % i, torch.nn.InstanceNorm1d(num_features=layers[i+1])))

            layer_list.append(('activation_%d' % i, self.activation()))

        layer_list.append(
            ('layer_%d' % (self.depth - 1), torch.nn.Linear(layers[-2], layers[-1]))
        )
        layerDict = OrderedDict(layer_list)

        # deploy layers
        self.layers = torch.nn.Sequential(layerDict)

    def output_vector(self):
    #"""Returns an unbatched vector field, i.e. assumes input is a 1D tensor."""
        F_fn, params = make_functional(self.layers)
        print(len(params))
        J_fn = torch.func.jacrev(F_fn, argnums=1)

        def A_fn(params, x):
            J = J_fn(params, x)
            A = J - J.T
            return A

        def A_flat_fn(params, x):
            A = A_fn(params, x)
            A_flat = A.reshape(-1)
            return A_flat

        def ddF(params, x):
            D = x.nelement()
            dA_flat = torch.func.jacrev(A_flat_fn, argnums=1)(params, x)
            Jac_all = dA_flat.reshape(D, D, D)
            ddF = torch.vmap(torch.trace)(Jac_all)
            return ddF

        return ddF, params, A_fn

    def forward(self, x):
        u_fn, params, A_fn = output_vector()
        u = torch.vmap(u_fn, in_dims=(None, 0))(params, x)
        #out = self.layers(x)
        return u

class PhysicsInformedNN_pbc():
    """PINNs (convection/diffusion/reaction) for periodic boundary conditions."""
    def __init__(self, system, X_u_train, u_train, X_f_train, bc_lb, bc_ub, layers, G, nu, beta, rho, optimizer_name, lr,
        net, L=1, activation='tanh', loss_style='mean'):

        self.system = system

        self.x_u = torch.tensor(X_u_train[:, 0:1], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.t_u = torch.tensor(X_u_train[:, 1:2], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.x_f = torch.tensor(X_f_train[:, 0:1], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.t_f = torch.tensor(X_f_train[:, 1:2], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.x_bc_lb = torch.tensor(bc_lb[:, 0:1], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.t_bc_lb = torch.tensor(bc_lb[:, 1:2], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.x_bc_ub = torch.tensor(bc_ub[:, 0:1], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.t_bc_ub = torch.tensor(bc_ub[:, 1:2], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.net = net

        if self.net == 'DNN':
            self.dnn = DNN(layers, activation).to(device)
        else: # "pretrained" can be included in model path
            # the dnn is within the PINNs class
            self.dnn = torch.load(net).dnn

        self.u = torch.tensor(u_train, requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.layers = layers
        self.nu = nu
        self.beta = beta
        self.rho = rho

        self.G = torch.tensor(G, requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        self.G = self.G.reshape(-1, 1)

        self.L = L

        self.lr = lr
        self.optimizer_name = optimizer_name

        self.optimizer = choose_optimizer(self.optimizer_name, self.dnn.parameters(), self.lr)

        self.loss_style = loss_style

        self.iter = 0

    def net_u(self, x, t):
        """The standard DNN that takes (x,t) --> u."""
        u = self.dnn(torch.cat([x, t], dim=1))
        return u          

    def net_f(self, x, t):
        """ Autograd for calculating the residual for different systems."""
        u = self.net_u(x, t)

        u_t = torch.autograd.grad(
            u, t,
            grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u),
            retain_graph=True,
            create_graph=True
        )[0]
        u_x = torch.autograd.grad(
            u, x,
            grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u),
            retain_graph=True,
            create_graph=True
        )[0]

        u_xx = torch.autograd.grad(
            u_x, x,
            grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u_x),
            retain_graph=True,
            create_graph=True
            )[0]

        if 'convection' in self.system or 'diffusion' in self.system:
            f = u_t - self.nu*u_xx + self.beta*u_x - self.G
        elif 'rd' in self.system:
            f = u_t - self.nu*u_xx - self.rho*u + self.rho*u**2
        elif 'reaction' in self.system:
            f = u_t - self.rho*u + self.rho*u**2
        return f

    def net_b_derivatives(self, u_lb, u_ub, x_bc_lb, x_bc_ub):
        """For taking BC derivatives."""

        u_lb_x = torch.autograd.grad(
            u_lb, x_bc_lb,
            grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u_lb),
            retain_graph=True,
            create_graph=True
            )[0]

        u_ub_x = torch.autograd.grad(
            u_ub, x_bc_ub,
            grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u_ub),
            retain_graph=True,
            create_graph=True
            )[0]

        return u_lb_x, u_ub_x

    def loss_pinn(self, verbose=True):
        """ Loss function. """
        if torch.is_grad_enabled():
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        u_pred = self.net_u(self.x_u, self.t_u)
        u_pred_lb = self.net_u(self.x_bc_lb, self.t_bc_lb)
        u_pred_ub = self.net_u(self.x_bc_ub, self.t_bc_ub)
        if self.nu != 0:
            u_pred_lb_x, u_pred_ub_x = self.net_b_derivatives(u_pred_lb, u_pred_ub, self.x_bc_lb, self.x_bc_ub)
        #f_pred = self.net_f(self.x_f, self.t_f)

        if self.loss_style == 'mean':
            loss_u = torch.mean((self.u - u_pred) ** 2)
            loss_b = torch.mean((u_pred_lb - u_pred_ub) ** 2)
            if self.nu != 0:
                loss_b += torch.mean((u_pred_lb_x - u_pred_ub_x) ** 2)
            #loss_f = torch.mean(f_pred ** 2)
        elif self.loss_style == 'sum':
            loss_u = torch.sum((self.u - u_pred) ** 2)
            loss_b = torch.sum((u_pred_lb - u_pred_ub) ** 2)
            if self.nu != 0:
                loss_b += torch.sum((u_pred_lb_x - u_pred_ub_x) ** 2)
            #loss_f = torch.sum(f_pred ** 2)

        loss = loss_u + loss_b #+ self.L*loss_f
        print(loss)
        if loss.requires_grad:
            loss.backward()

        grad_norm = 0
        for p in self.dnn.parameters():
            print(p.grad)
            param_norm = p.grad.detach().data.norm(2)
            grad_norm += param_norm.item() ** 2
        grad_norm = grad_norm ** 0.5

        if verbose:
            if self.iter % 100 == 0:
                print(
                    'epoch %d, gradient: %.5e, loss: %.5e, loss_u: %.5e, loss_b: %.5e, loss_f: %.5e' % (self.iter, grad_norm, loss.item(), loss_u.item(), loss_b.item(), loss_f.item())
                )
            self.iter += 1

        return loss

    def train(self):
        self.dnn.train()
        self.optimizer.step(self.loss_pinn)

    def predict(self, X):
        x = torch.tensor(X[:, 0:1], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)
        t = torch.tensor(X[:, 1:2], requires_grad=True).float().to(device)

        self.dnn.eval()
        u = self.net_u(x, t)
        u = u.detach().cpu().numpy()

        return u
```

I tried different methods for calculating gradients of u with respect to x and t. but they all return the same error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).